# Как перебрать значения из JSON файла?

Tags: python, json

Я просто не понимаю, что делать дальше. Необходимо перебрать строку из `JSON` и, если значение `True`, вывести `--READY--`
помогите пожалуйста!

```
import json
from pprint import pprint 
with open( 'zadaniye1.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f: 
    text = json.load(f) 
    pprint(text)
```

Comment: Что значит «перебрать строку»? Значение чего должно быть True? Какие конкретно данные записаны в файле и откуда уверенность, что к ним вообще можно употреблять термин «перебрать»?

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос примером того, как выглядит ваш `zadaniye1.json` и пример того, что вы хотите получить. Вообще, пишите конкретнее, так как сейчас ничего непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Json по сути представляет из себя словарь. Ключ: значение.

```
dictionary = eval(json_text.translate({'true':'True','false':'False','null':'None','undefined':'None'})
# Синтаксис отличается, по этому нужно сначала записать строку правильно, а потом уже выполнить как код Python
```

Есть специальные библиотеки по работе с JSON файлами, но этот код по идее тоже должен корректно выполниться

Comment: Не надо `eval` использовать где ни попадя, это очень опасная практика.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не проверить строку на True

```
# открываем файл
with open('zadaniye1.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # проходимся по каждой строке
    for line in file:
        # если строка равна True вывести "--READY--"
        if line == 'True':
            print('--READY--')
```